# General select statement to stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedure

I'm trying to write a general function to several specific stored procedures, but I'm afraid that it will cause errors that I don't see now. The function is to get the name of the stored procedure as a string, and get a list of objects that contain the parameters of the stored procedure. Does it look good to you?

```
public static DataTable SelectQuery(string storedProcedureName, List<object> parameters)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbConnection con = WorkerDB.GetConnection();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;  
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", parameters[i]);
        }
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            da.Dispose();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Where best to put the try...catch..finally in that code?

Answer (score 5):

This is first refactored version of your code. I have changed following thing

1. If any object provide dispose method , prefer **using** statement.
2. Use dictionary rather than list of parameter as you have a possibility of specifying param names also
3. Current implementation sticks only to datatable , you might need to think about the datareader.
4. naming of variable should be explicit.

Few more things needs to be thought like out param if you need.

```
public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string queryName, CommandType commandType, Dictionary<string,object> parameters=null)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection =  WorkerDB.GetConnection())
    {
        using (var command=new OleDbCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = queryName;
            command.CommandType = commandType;
            command.Connection = connection;


            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                } 
            }

            var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            dataAdapter.Dispose();

            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this:

> ```
> catch (Exception ex)
> {
>     throw ex;
> }
> ```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182363.aspx)

> Once an exception is thrown, part of the information it carries is the
>   stack trace ... If an exception is re-thrown by
>   specifying the exception in the **throw** statement, the stack trace is
>   restarted at the current method and the list of method calls between
>   the original method that threw the exception and the current method is
>   lost. To keep the original stack trace information with the exception,
>   use the **throw** statement without specifying the exception.

Comment: I'd like to add that simply catching and re-throwing does not serve any purpose. If you're going to catch an exception, do something with it, otherwise let it bubble up to the global exception handler.

Comment: @VincePanuccio my point was that rethrowing in this way is actually worse than useless as you lose the stack trace.